# ORA-00904: invalid column name but I am using the correct column name

Tags: oracle

Can someone see where I am going wrong in the below query? I am getting the error message that the `GROUP BY` column doesn't exist, but it clearly does as I see that column name in the output when I don't use the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
           (SELECT customer_address.post_code FROM customer_address WHERE customer_address.address_type = 0 AND customer_address.customer_no = orders.customer_no) postcode, SUM(orders.order_no) orders
FROM
           orders, customer_address
WHERE
           orders.delivery_date = '27-MAY-15'
GROUP BY
           postcode;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: You cannot use an alias name in GROUP BY.

So:

```
GROUP BY (SELECT customer_address.post_code ...);
```

Or:

```
select postcode, sum(order_no)
from
(
  SELECT
    (SELECT customer_address.post_code FROM customer_address WHERE customer_address.address_type = 0 AND customer_address.customer_no = orders.customer_no) postcode, 
    orders.order_no
  FROM orders, customer_address
  WHERE orders.delivery_date = '27-MAY-15'
)
GROUP BY postcode;
```

EDIT:

However, your query seems wrong. Why do you cross-join orders and customer_address? By mistake I guess. Use explicit joins (`INNER JOIN customer_address ON ...`), when using joins to avoid such errors. But here I guess you'd just have to remove `, customer_address`.

Then why do you add order numbers? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Another side note: Don't use such date literals as above. You are relying on the current setting to match your string, which might fail. Either use ISO date literals instead (`DATE'2015-05-27'`) or convert your string properly: `to_date('27-MAY-15', 'dd-mon-yy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')`.

Comment: To answer your questions; I am wanting to see the amount of orders we delivered to each customer (by their postcode) today. Does it make sense now?

Comment: The amount of orders should be `COUNT(DISTINCT order_no)`, because you want to *count* orders (without counting duplicates). If you SUM two order numbers #10001 and #10002 instead you get 20003, a number without any meaning.